# #1052 - Column 'bookingId' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

I want to join to two table but I got a problem

Here is my SQL syntax

```
select * from booking as b,
booking_detail as bd 
WHERE bookingId = 9 AND b.bookingId = bd.bookingId
```

Here is I got error:

> # 1052 - Column 'bookingId' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: A useful rule-of-thumb: NEVER use evil `SELECT *`. Instead always name and qualify the columns you actually want returned. Then, also, name and qualify the columns you wish to join on.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

use alias for `b.bookingId = 9`

```
select * from booking as b join 
booking_detail as bd on b.bookingId = bd.bookingId
WHERE b.bookingId = 9
```

Answer (score 1):

use join and alias name for bookinid column because of this column available in both table

```
select * from booking as b join
 booking_detail as bd 
 on b.bookingId = bd.bookingId
  WHERE b.bookingId = 9
```